# Remove everything from string before given variable

Tags: powershell

I have a string `some\string/with/**/special\chars\haha`. In variable I hold `chars` string and I try to remove everything before and including `chars` so expected output would be `\haha`

I tried sth like:

```
$temp = "some\string/with/**/special\chars\haha"
$tmp="chars"
$temp -replace '(?s)^.*$tmp', ''
```

and

`$temp -replace '(?s)^.*$([regex]::Escape($tmp))', ''`

but the only thing that works is when I put the string directly into regex condition. Only this example gives expected output:

`$temp -replace '(?s)^.*chars', ''`

What am I doing wrong?

Edit.:
I need to use variable in regex, because I iterate through multiple strings like this one and not always the part I want to remove has the same string (example: `some\string/with/**/special\chars\haha -> \haha`; `C:\st/h/*/1234\asdf\x -> \x`). So in conclusion I have a problem using variable in regex, not with the regex itself as that works as intended when I replace variable with string (as shown above)

Comment: The PS tag is not valid on this post. I'm confused by your question, you're technically doing nothing wrong since you have the expected output with the final command

Comment: I need to use variable in regex. When I use variable output of the command is the same as input. On the other hand when I use string like in example in question I receive correct output. So I need help with using the variable in regex. I'll further clarify the question

Comment: The variable `$tmp` is not being replaced here because single-quoted strings are not subject to string interpolation: `'(?s)^.*$tmp'`.  Replacing the quotes will enable this feature, but I'm not sure your regex will then give the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's because you are using single quotes in your regex instead of double quotes. This means that the variable `$tpm` isn't being used.

Here is what your code should look like:

```
$temp = "some\string/with/**/special\chars\haha"
$tmp="chars"
$temp -replace "(?s)^.*$tmp", ''
```

Your code was using $tmp instead of the actual value inside the $tmp variable.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. Your answer together with commend of @boxdog explained what I did wrong. As that precisely addresses my question this is accepted answer.

 **For future readers - answer of Justin Cooksey is working too!

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$temp = "some\string/with/**/special\chars\haha"
$tmp="chars"
$regex = '(?s)^.*' + $tmp
$temp -replace $regex, ''
```